# How do I specify vertex normals on a mesh?

Tags: three.js

I'm importing a mesh and have already computed the vertex normals for it. I want to use my normals instead of calling computeVertexNormals() for the geometry object. Right now I have

```
var geometry = THREE.Geometry();
// fill in vertex, face and texture
// ...
// compute normals
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();  // <-- Would like to replace this
```

There is a reference in the docs to using a buffer attribute but no examples.
http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=vertex#Reference/Core/BufferAttribute

Does anyone know how to do this?

thanks,

john

Comment: I noticed this has gone unanswered. I looked at the source to understand how they add the Float32Array. See the native function here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/302c693b27663d4d280b156b5ebe4ed38cd062e4/src/core/BufferGeometry.js#L637 It appears "this.addAttribute" at line 649 creates the object which makes attributes.normal.array available at line 665 where it's populated at will. I'd imagine this is how you'd add your own, wherein "this" is the instance of geometry or buffergeometry.

Comment: Thank you, I see that in the code. If that is the supported way to do it I'll explore that.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a THREE.Geometry object the vertex normals are stored with the faces. If NormalList contains the normal vectors for the vertices then this loop will do it.

```
/*
 * Add the normals. They are added to the face array
 */
for ( f = 0, fl = geometry.faces.length; f < fl; f ++ ) {


var face = geometry.faces[ f ];

var ndx = face.a;           
var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
normal.x = NormalList[ndx].x;
normal.y = NormalList[ndx].y;
normal.z = NormalList[ndx].z;
face.vertexNormals[ 0 ] = normal;

ndx = face.b;  
normal = new THREE.Vector3();
normal.x = NormalList[ndx].x;
normal.y = NormalList[ndx].y;
normal.z = NormalList[ndx].z;
face.vertexNormals[ 1 ] = normal;

ndx = face.c;
normal = new THREE.Vector3();
normal.x = NormalList[ndx].x;
normal.y = NormalList[ndx].y;
normal.z = NormalList[ndx].z;
face.vertexNormals[ 2 ] = normal;


}
```